# Navigation using parameter not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

So what im trying to do, is that i have a route which is /product defined in my app.js and it has a parameter of id

App.js

```
 <Route path='/product' element={<Product  />} />
```

Product.js

```
export const Product = ({ ID }) => {
```

what im trying to navigate to the page /product using 'useNavigate()' and  pass an id i have so i can use it there by doing so, however it's not working and showing as undefined.Does anyone have any clue about how to fix this?

```
const handleOpen = (id) => {
   navigate('/product',{ state: { id: id } }); };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useLocation` to get the state:

```js
export const Product = () => {
   const location = useLocation();
   const { id } = location.state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, the path to your prop should be `props.location.state.id` in the `<Product />` page.